# Where is arm-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 or where can I change the compiler?

Tags: xcode, g++, arm, static-libraries

I want to compile a lib for arm architecture. Apparently Xcode has inserted a path "arm-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2".

Two Questions:

1. Where can I change this setting?
2. I only find the arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2 on my system, how can I update to arm-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2?

Answer (score 1):

The XCode compiler can usually be selected by clicking your project and then selecting "Build Settings" and there under "Build Options".

Darwin11 is OS X Lion 10.7, 
so when you want to upgrade the compiler, you will have to upgrade your OS and reinstall XCode.

Edit: As I just have seen, there seems to be no darwin11 variant for the arm compiler. There is only a i686 (and x86_64)-apple-darwin11 compiler.

Maybe the darwin11 for arm is in the next release? I don't know...but XCode 4.2.1(4D502) - the current production release - shouldn't be referring to an arm-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 .

There is, however, a directory called arm-apple-darwin11 in the 10.7 SDK directories, but on my system (10.7.2 latest MBA, never had 10.6 installed on it) its empty.

Comment: I yesterday completely removed devtools and reinstalled Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

apple darwin is the core of OSX, I think the easiest way (if not the only one) to get darwin 11 running is to upgrade your OSX to 10.7.1

edit: damn cli_hlt you're fast!

Comment: Did you upgrade from 10.6 ? I had some trouble with the old xcode, it left some pieces behind when I upgraded and uninstalled xcode. Not all of the components were deleted and the new xcode didnt install some pieces. Finally got it to work by completely removing xcode in some way, I'll try to find the method I used to get rid of it. 

Might have been this one: > sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all

Comment: I did this one yesterday: sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all. I wonder, if such a compiler already exists..